# C++ opengl instancing color PER vertex (THREE unique colors per triangle)

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, vertex

Overview: I am trying to make the leap from draw calls to instancing. I want to maintain control over individual vertex colors.

Working materials: C++, OpenGL, Macos. I am working with three quads. Three quads * two unique triangles per quad = 18 individual vertices.

Desired outcome: Three quads whose colors are interpolated by 18 total unique user-determined vertex colors. Six unique colors per quad.

What I can do: I am presently able to instance the transformation matrix of vertex position and produce 3 deliberately positioned quads.

What I cannot do yet: I have been unable to make my setup  retrieve exactly one color per each incoming vertex.
This is the minimum case as I know to represent this. Minimum in that it has model vertex position, transformation position, and (hopefully) *unique color.

What I have tried: Reading a ton of Kronos function signatures, exploring all the parameter space, to the point of futility, of the finite changeable values in the glBufferData(), glVertexAttribPointer() and glDrawArraysInstanced() functions.

main.cpp:

```
#define VTXPOSLOC 0 // Vertex Position Location
#define INSCOLLOC 1 // Instance Color Location
#define INSMATLOC 2 // Instance Matrix Location
...
float vtxdat[18]   = {  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    std::vector <glm::mat4> iMV; // instanceMatricesVec
    std::vector <glm::vec3> iCV; // instanceColorsVec
    unsigned int instanceCount = 3;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<instanceCount; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<6; j++) // 6 == number of vertices req to make TWO unique triangles in vtxdat
        {
            float xC = j/2.0f; 
            float yC = i/2.0f;
            glm::vec3 colorvec3 = glm::vec3(xC,yC,0.0f);
            iCV.push_back(colorvec3);
        }

        glm::mat4 transmat4 = glm::translate ( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3 ( i,0,0 ) );
        iMV.push_back(transmat4);
    }
    glUseProgram      ( shadprogID ); // Does NOT need to be here. ONLY in while loop.
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1, &VAO );
    glBindVertexArray ( VAO );
    glGenBuffers      ( 1, &VBO );
    glBindBuffer      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO );
    glBufferData      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vtxdat),vtxdat,GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer     ( VTXPOSLOC,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(float),(void*)(0*sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( VTXPOSLOC );
    
    glGenBuffers      ( 1, &colorVBO );
    glBindBuffer      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,colorVBO );
    glBufferData      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,iCV.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3),iCV.data(),GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer     ( INSCOLLOC,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,6*sizeof(float),(void*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( INSCOLLOC );
    
    glGenBuffers      ( 1, &instanceVBO );
    glBindBuffer      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,instanceVBO );
    glBufferData      ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,iMV.size() * sizeof(glm::mat4),iMV.data(),GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        glVertexAttribPointer     ( INSMATLOC+i,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(glm::mat4),(void*)(i*sizeof(glm::vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray ( INSMATLOC+i );
        glVertexAttribDivisor     ( INSMATLOC+i, 1 );
    }

    while ( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 ) {
...        
        glm::mat4 projmat4 = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)WINDOWWIDTH / (float)WINDOWHEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 viewmat4 = glm::lookAt(camPs, camPs + camFr, camUp);
        
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projmat4ID, 1, GL_FALSE, &projmat4[0][0]); // to vs
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewmat4ID, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewmat4[0][0]); // to vs
              
        glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6, instanceCount);
...
    };
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vtxPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 iCV;
layout(location = 2) in mat4 iMV;
out vec3 fragmentColor;
uniform mat4 projmat4;
uniform mat4 viewmat4;
void main(){
    vec4 transformedPos = iMV * vec4(vtxPos,1.0f);
    gl_Position = projmat4 * viewmat4 * transformedPos;
    fragmentColor = iCV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your colour values seems a little odd?

```cpp
            float xC = j / 2.0f; 
            float yC = i / 2.0f;
```

Especially considering your stride:

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(INSCOLLOC, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(float),(void*)(0));
```

They'd be mostly above 1.0, is that intentional?

Anyhow, I think I see what you're trying to do:

```cpp
    unsigned int instanceCount = 3;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<instanceCount; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<6; j++) // 6 == number of vertices req to make TWO unique triangles in vtxdat
        {
            float xC = j/2.0f; 
            float yC = i/2.0f;
            glm::vec3 colorvec3 = glm::vec3(xC,yC,0.0f);
            iCV.push_back(colorvec3);
        }

        glm::mat4 transmat4 = glm::translate ( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3 ( i,0,0 ) );
        iMV.push_back(transmat4);
    }
```

This isn't going to work sadly. Instance0 will use colours [0:5]. Instance1 will use colours [0:5]. Instance2 will use colours [0:5].

The problem is that when rendering instances, your vertex & colour buffers are reset back to the start of the VBO's. Those params for which you have set the attribute divisor to 1 will advance once per instance. There is no way to make the colour VBOs advance past the first 6 entries.

You basically have two ways you can solve this.

1. Load the colour data as a texture *(i.e. 6 x 3 pixels, for NumVerts * NumInstances)*. You should then be able to do a texelfetch using the vertex & instance IDs in the shader.

```cpp
uniform sampler2D colours;

void main() {
   vec4 colour = texelFetch(colours, ivec2(gl_VertexID, gl_InstanceID), 0);
}
```

2. Use a shader storage buffer.

```cpp
layout(std430, binding = 3) buffer colour_buffer
{
    vec4 colours[];
};

void main() {
   vec4 col = colours[gl_InstanceID * 6 + gl_VertexID];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am on a mac, therefore opengl is capped at 4.1, therefore shader storage buffer is not an option. I have spent a great deal of time trying to make your algorithm work (on this mac), to no avail. I can make the texture.png with user-commanded colors, and can load that and send it to the shader. I had to manually send the instance index, so I at least had a workaround there. I have done everything within my sanity to make gl_VertexID function in this context, and it does not function. It is locked on "2", the third vertex.